# UIViews move when other UIViews is set hidden

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

In my View I have an UIImageView placed in the center a little bit above the vertical center line. Let's call it Logo.

http://i63.tinypic.com/14dhfeu.png

In the Bottom I have a UIView which is rectangle placed below the bottom line (so it's just the UIView's top that can be seen in the view. This view is called PopUpView.

When pressing PopUpView the PopUpView is moved to the center of self.view by:

```
   >self.PopUpView.frame.origin.y = self.PopUpView.frame.origin.y-300;
```

The PopUpView has a small margin on all sides to self.view.

In addition I move the Logo up and out of the view, as the PopUpVie is semi transparent. Like this:

http://i64.tinypic.com/hrdnwj.png

In the PopUpView which is now placed in the center I have a button. When pressing that button a new UIView is presented by setting sethidden=NO (This UIView is called PopUpView2 and has a frame equal to self.view). That UIView also has a button to close it. Like this:

Link4 (See comments)

When the Close button is pressed the PopUpView2 is set hidden again. The code is:

> - (IBAction) CloseRate:(id)sender{
>
>   [self.PopUpView2 setHidden:YES];
>
> }

BUT, the weird thing is that, PopUpView is now moved back down (as it is when view is loaded initially). But the Logo is still placed above the self.view:

Link 3 (see comments)

So all in all, when one UIView is set hidden, another UIView is moved, but then again a third UIView is not moved.

Can somebody explain this?

Regards,
Christian

Comment: you can link to images

Comment: pls, put the code for Close Button IBAction

Comment: Link 3: http://i63.tinypic.com/13zqywj.png
Link 4: http://oi64.tinypic.com/2yo2trr.jpg

Comment: @Wain Thanks! Still limited to two links pr. question, but added the rest in the comment above.

Comment: @CCastro Edited in the original post :) thanks!

Comment: Well, I was thinking you had more code.

Comment: Well, it's just an IBAction. Have edited the original post :)

Comment: Just found one more interesting thing. Second time I try to open PopUpView2 and then close it, it closes as it should do. That is, with PopUpView centered in the self.view.... weird.